# Red dot on Suggested Edit review Queue

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-queue

I just noticed a red dot in the Review Queue, besides the Suggested Edits:

[image]

This I have never seen before, and I wonder what could that red dot probably mean?

Usually it is a gray dot, and it goes away when the queue empties. This time, even though that queue is empty (as seen when clicking on it as well as on the [all reviews](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review) page) the red dot won't go away. Could it be some bug or is it by-design?

**Update:** After aprox. 10 minutes of refreshing and checking the Reviews the Red Dot disappeared. Still leaves me with the doubt of the meaning of that red dot, as it is the first time I see such dot in any SE site.

**Second Update:** Seems like today (9 days after original post) this problem reappeared, where the red dot was visible but when accessed no reviews were available (at least to me):

[image]

Could this mean we actually need to bump the threshold up a bit? <sub>(Could it be related to the fact that I just did several Tag Excerpt edits that need approval?)</sub>

Comment: possibly related: [Is there an issue with the review queue indicator today?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358151/839601) (at MSO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red dot means that a larger-than-average number of items are awaiting review.  "Average" is taken loosely; it's a threshold based on the size of our site and not our specific review history.  ([For us it's 3 for suggested edits.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/162102)) The red dot is an indicator that this would be a good time to do some extra reviewing.

The gray dot appears if there is anything waiting in the queue.

Update: according to [this MSO discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358151/839601) (h/t gnat), if you went to the queue and found nothing to review even though you saw a red dot, it might be because several other reviewers were in there at the same time and beat you to those items.  See the comment from Shog below about bumping up the "red threshold" here.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that :) seem that this behavior was really similar as what @gnat suggested in comments. They ended up raising the threshold a bit... (could it be the same in this case?)

Comment: Yep, we'll probably want to bump it up slightly here; there were a couple of people actively reviewing at the same time, and edits aren't assigned to multiple reviewers simultaneously.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Sorry I got too carried away with my hatred of Stack Exchange employees. My apologies for the rude comments directed at you unintentionally in the process. I came here to delete my comments, but it looks like that is already taken care of. Edit: Just to be clear on this, my apology is only for the rude comments made to Monica. I have absolutely no regrets about my hatred of the Stack Exchange employees riding on their high horses, and there is no reason to apologise to them.

Comment: For the record: our horses are never high. We need them to navigate.

Comment: @Shog9 the only way I can think a horse would be able to navigate the Seas of Communities is by being high ;)

Comment: @shog9 Here you go: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+off+high+horse

Comment: I updated the question @Shog9 as I experienced this again today. Could be due to some tag wiki edits I did that need approval. What do you think? Time to bump up the threshold?

Comment: It was - see my reply to your other comment on the other post where you just pinged me @DarkCygnus.

Comment: @Shog9 I see, thanks for clearing this out :) and sorry if I startled you with this update. Will have in mind next time I do tag wiki edits.

Comment: FWIW, I did the experiment and I just did some more wiki edits and the dot reappeared. I guess that compared to the amount of regular suggested edits, the ones I did are proportionally bigger.