# Why do we have so many close votes reviews?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-queue

Recently, I've noticed the red dot indicating there are a lot of close votes to be reviewed pretty much every time I get on the site. Is this a bug or do we actually have a deficit of close votes reviews?

Comment: There are currently 22 items in the close queue, compared to 0-3 in the others.  I haven't been tracking this recently to know if those are typical numbers.

Comment: @MonicaCellio this seems pretty in line to what I've been seeing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Red dot on Suggested Edit review Queue](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/red-dot-on-suggested-edit-review-queue)

Comment: We have a small group of folks who very actively like to cast close votes, triggering reviews. And we don't have enough folks who care to constantly review these questions in the queue. Thus, red dots.

Answer (score 8):

There's a deficit of people to review those close votes.

We simply need more people to step up and go through the review queues on a regular basis.  We moderators can't do this as our votes are immediate and binding.  We'd much prefer users to reach a consensus on reviewing questions.

Comment: Is it possible to lower the rep threshold for reviewing on the stack without affecting others?  Or to lower the number of confirming votes?

Comment: @WGroleau AFAIK that would normally need to be adjusted globally for stack exchange and be a question for meta.SE.  They've generally been trying to make site function more similar not less though so I suspect a workplace specific change isn't likely.  OTOH last month they ran an experiment on Stackoverflow with only 3 votes needed to close a question.  Results from it haven't been published yet.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-ended-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-day

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be a large number of close votes being cast on here in general - more than most other SE sites I frequent.

Perhaps there should be a review of the VTC categories and/or the guidelines for what is considered on topic here? Workplace issues are not a science. Most questions and answers on TWP are to some extent opinion- and personal-experience based. If most of the VTCs that are cast were approved, then there wouldn't be any questions on here at all!

Comment: Yes, we have lots of close votes. They don't appear to have anything at all to do with the categories or guidelines. IMHO, it's just some folks who like to rush to close questions.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere i've always found it strange that there seem to be so many more VTCs here than on other SE sites. I don't know if there is any hard data to back that up though - it could just be a false-perception on my part.

Comment: There do seem to be too many VTCs here, IMHO. I don't frequent other SE sites enough to know if it is common across the SE platform or unique to us.